# Keyboard covers EditText after clicking EditText when EditText in edit mode

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

My case: EditText has no focus, I click EditText, Software Keyboard has displayed, EditText has focus, EditText is not covered by Software Keyboard. Now I click again on EditText ( now  EditText has focus ) - keyboard is "reloaded" and it covers EditText. I has no on click listener set to EditText, focusable_in_touch_mode set to true otherwise keyboard won't be displayed. I tried adjustPan, adjustResize with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Put your layout in scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

just modify your that particular activity in the manifest with the following code,just add this line in that

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

For example your activity is MainActivity the you can solve your problem like this

```
<activity
        android:name="com.my.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
```

or try this instead of the above line in the activity in your manifest

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Answer (score 0):

```
1) first put your EditText inside Scroolview in xml file

2) In Java file ,  do as below.


Edittext et_search=(Edittext)findviewByid(R.id.et_search);

Scrollview scroll=(Scrollview)findviewByid(R.id.scroll);

et_search.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasfocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(hasfocus)
                {

                    if(et_search.requestFocus()==true)
                    {
                        scroll.scrollTo(0,scroll.getBottom());
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```